# Linux Web-Base Management Tool or Platform, What is/are the best(s)

Tags: ubuntu, web-applications

A lots of Linux Distro are result to lots of options. By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 8.04LTS - Server for our File Server, and Sadly Stop today. I'd used eBox Platform for managing the Linux system. Happily enjoying "create/copy/paste" of files unto the server with its own samba profile lasting for a week. Then the nasty bugs accord. Resulting to Linux kernel Panic, due to some of buggy eBox Modules Written in Perl. The Question is: What is the best Linux Web-Base Management Tool or Platform?

Options
1. eBox Platform (which i marked it negative)
2. Webmin
3. ISConfig

Which one you like, or maybe the best for you.
Note: Ubuntu 8.04LTS - Server is my Linux Distro

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of your server?  Is it strictly a samba/fileserver?  There are several options for webservers or database servers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think for a general purpose web console, **webmin** is the standard.

The thing I really like about webmin is that **it works with your standard config files**, so you can edit them either by hand, or using webmin - or stop using webmin altogether, and your config files are still consistent.

Comment: For the question asked, good answer.  Although I'm a bit negative about GUI administration in general and would advise to learn how to do it from the commandline.  It'll suck at first, but in the long run you'll be much better off.

At least with webmin, you have the option of both until you are comfortable on the commandline.

Comment: Where webmin really shines is when you as the main administrator get sick or hit by a bus, and your windows administrator has to do your job :)

Answer (score 1):

ISPConfig is an open source hosting control panel for Linux. ISPConfig is licensed under BSD license.

Managed Services

```
* Httpd (virtual hosts, domain and IP based)
* FTP
* Bind (A, CNAME, MX and SPF Records)
* POP3 Auto-Responder
* MySQL client-databases
* Webalizer statistics
* Harddisk quota
* Mail-Quota
* Traffic limits
* IP-addresses
* SSL
* SSI
* Shell-access
* Mailscanner (Antivirus)
* Firewall
```

ispconfig.org

Answer (score 0):

For single-application servers, there are many options:

For managing Database servers, try **phpmyadmin**

For managing webservers/web-hosting situations, **virtualmin** is very nice, or **cpanel** is another option